# Check exchange 2013 mailbox, for any un-answered emails and send an email alert (server side)

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I have been doing some research for sometime, trying to find if it is possible to do the following.

Send a email to X if a mailbox has emails that have not been replied to in 7 days. This mailbox will have out of office enabled so someone sending an email to this mailbox will get an auto reply. I have been asked if it is possible to have some sort of alert setup if the email received has not been physically replied to within 7 days.

1. Out of office will be enabled on the mailbox
2. Someone needs to know if any of the received has been replied to by an actual person, not the oof message
3. server side, no client side rule

From my research i cannot find a way to accomplish this.

If anyone has any methods of accomplishing this, i would be very grateful for a solution. I have not found any powershell scripts that can do this as of yet!